# How to permit a standard user open the partitions without requiring the Admin password?

Tags: permissions

I am Using Ubuntu 20.04

I have a system administrated by me. username `abc`
I have a standard user `xyz`

while installing Ubuntu I have created two partitions for data storage.

now I want to access both me and the standard user these partitions and do what ever we want, I mean delete, create modify etc both have the same rights. It is fine when I login, I mean it does not ask password. But when the user `xyz` tries to open.. it asks for admin password.

Is there a way to achieve this without using `chown` command?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, edit the `/etc/sudoers` file using the command `sudo visudo` and add the line `xyz ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount, /usr/bin/umount` to the last. Install vim editor beforehand in case it is not installed.

Comment: Hi PrakashS@ will not it give sudo previliges to standard user?? or similar rights to standard user??

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve this without using chown command?

Yes. `chmod` can be used to set a group too but if you do not want to use that there are altenatives:

- Use `chgrp`. Add all users to a group and change the group of the partition to this
  group. And new users can be added to this group.
- Or use `sudo setfacl -m u:{user}:wrx /mountpoint/`  or `sudo setfacl -m g:{group}:wrx /mountpoint/`

And you can add new users to this group  with ...

```
sudo adduser {new_user} {group}
```

Using `sudoers` seems overkill to me :P

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @Rinzwind.. I am going through your post.. and want to do it rite now.. but struck.. shall I use your point 1 or point 2..

Comment: I have two partitions /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda4 where to start.. I am struggling.. This system will have only those two users as I mentioned in the Q.. abc its me admin and xyz standard user..

Comment: `sudo setfacl -m u:xyz:wrx /dev/sda3` this should be the practical command in my case?

Comment: either should work!  and yes `sudo setfacl -m u:xyz:wrx /dev/sda3`  plus `sudo setfacl -m u:xyz:wrx /dev/sda4`  if sda3 and sda4 are your disks. But why not chmod? That is a far easier command.

Comment: i tried above commands but without success.. I will still try above commands.. I am new to Linux and afraid of `chmod` thats why avoiding it but once I get success with above commands.. will try `chmod` thanks for ur support..